# Android Studio / ¿Como cambiar color de txts en Recycler View según su contenido?

Tags: android, android-studio

Tengo un recycler view el cual tiene solamente un text view adentro. A este text view, el usuario le cargará valores desde 0 a 5 (pueden haber decimales ej.: 4.3).

Quiero que los textos tengan diferentes colores dependiendo del número que el usuario haya introducido. Por ejemplo, para los números mayores a 4.5 (4.6, 4.7, 4.8, 4.9, 5) se les asignará el color verde.

Como puedo lograr esto?

**Adjunto el código JAVA del adaptador de mi recycler view en el cual estoy intentando cambiar los colores (no obtengo resultados)**

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(adapter_recycler_resultados.ViewHolderDatos 
holder, int position){
holder.numeros.setText(array_recycler_numeros.get(position).getNumeros());
if(Integer.parseInt(array_recycler_numeros.get(position).getNumeros()) > 4.5){
       holder.numeros.setTextColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.colorNotSelected));
    }}
```

Por que está mal lo que estoy haciendo? Como puedo conseguir el resultado que espero? **Gracias por leer**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Es algo super sencillo. Probá con el siguiente código:

```
 if(Float.parseFloat(array_model_recycler_resultados.get(position).getCalificacion()) >= 4.5){
        holder.calificacion.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#006064"));
    }
```

Espero te sirva!

Comment: Funcionó!!!! Muchas gracias!